# Delphi Android set zoom for TWebBrowser

Tags: android, delphi, webview

I'm using a TWebBrowser component in my (very simple) Android app written in Delphi 11.3, which is displayed when the app is started. But the website is zoomed in quite a lot, and I want it to be zoomed out to fit the width of the screen. How can I achieved that?

I found a lot of tips for doing it in Java, like a call to jWebView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL), but I could not find the equivalent of this in Delphi.

Any hints will be much appreciated!